# How to write a custom mouse wheel event handler in OrbitControls?

Tags: three.js, mousewheel, orbitcontrols

I'm working on a WebGL application using ThreeJS and OrbitControls. How do I write and make use of a custom event handler for wheel spin events?

Suppose my custom handler is

```
function custom_handleMouseWheel(event) { ... }
```

I tried adding it as a listener:

```
window.addEventListener("wheel", custom_handleMouseWheel);
```

but I suspect this adds my handler to a list of existing handlers (probably only one), and I'd have to remove the original handler. Not sure how to do that. And anyway, my handler never was called, which I checked for by adding a console.log("Wheel!") line to my handler.

Another thing I tried is to replace the handleWheelMouse method in the controls object, like this:

```
let original_handleMouseWheel;

function custom_handleMouseWheel(event) {
  console.log("Custom Wheel!");
  ... fancy geometry calculations ...
  original_handleMouseWheel(event);
}

// somewhere after defining scene, camera, renderer, etc...
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
original_handleMouseWheel = controls.handleMouseWheel;
controls.handleMouseWheel = custom_handleMouseWheel;
```

but again the console.log line never executes.

What is  the right way to go about doing this?

Comment: Just setting `controls.enableZoom = false` will stop the [default zoom](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js#L58). The default "wheel" listener is [added](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js#L1043) to the "domElement" which should be the second parameter sent to the OrbitControls constructor. try `renderer.domElement.addEventListener('wheel', custom_handleMouseWheel);`

Comment: That did the trick!  A simple thing that I somehow didn't know.  Make this an answer not a comment, and you've earned a big green checkmark!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just setting `controls.enableZoom = false` will stop the [default zoom](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js#L58).
The default "wheel" listener is [added](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js#L1043) to the "domElement" which should be the second parameter sent to the OrbitControls constructor.
Try `renderer.domElement.addEventListener('wheel', custom_handleMouseWheel);`